# Remove blank pages in twosided book class without openany

Tags: double-sided

I am writing my thesis using

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
```

At the end of chapters, I get a blank page. This is because chapters start from right side (Odd page number, [RO] and that at the end of each chapter book.cls has a \clearpage by default. I do not want Openany as a solution.

How do I adjust my TeX document then to remove these blank pages?

thanks

Comment: What's wrong with `openany`? Oh, and welcome to TeX.sx!

Comment: I want my main chapters to be on RO. But, my references can start from any page.

Comment: @abhishek, what is RO?

Comment: So you should edit the references environment.

Comment: If you want your chapters to start on a right page (odd numbered), why should the bibliography chapter be different?

Answer (score 8):

It's really questionable to have all chapters start on a right hand page, but not the bibliography.

However, this can be accomplished in a really easy way:

```
\begingroup
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\bibliography{<bibfile>}
\endgroup
```

If you use directly the `thebibliography` environment it's just the same:

```
\begingroup
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem ...

...

\end{thebibliography}
\endgroup
```

Answer (score 2):

From `book.cls` we have

```
\newcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
```

If you only want to start a new page remove the `if` line inserting in your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{\clearpage
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\makeatother
```

Comment: But now, my citations look weird. I have apalike style. I see citations like (t,a) instead of (Rick et al..etc..)

Comment: There is no relation between the code above and the citations. Are you using `bibtex`?

Comment: I know...but, why would it change then..yes, I am using bibtex.

Comment: Hum, I have no experience with it. Let's wait the expert ones.

Comment: hmm...I thought you were one :-P  I just inactivated newclude and it changed all my aux and toc files - so, I will clean it up and re-run to see if it works.

Comment: ok..now, I know...I tried \newclude and it sucked badly. I deleted all toc and aux files. and deactivated newclude package, use \input, copied your code in book class, and Life is good again!

Comment: Sorry, but this is the same as saying `openany`.

Comment: @egreg, I agree, but the OP said *without using `openany`*. lol

Comment: @abhishek, see the @egreg's comment. You should use `openany`. Your problem with references is not related with this.

Comment: ok...I thought openany does not restrict the chapters on [RO]. but, seems like I am wrong. anyways, your solution works fine. Openany works fine too. thanks all.