# Force 'openany' half way through document

Tags: double-sided

I am using a double sided document for my report, which always have new chapters starting on a page to the right, which sometimes means leaving a page blank. However, for my appendix I would like to not leave any pages blank. Is it possible to force the 'openany' command after the conclusion? Or in some other way remove the blank pages?

I could perhaps also separate my appendix using a different command than \chapter, but I like the table of contents as shown below:

[image: Table of Contents]

Comment: In case you use KOMA-Script, just say `\KOMAoptions{openany}` before the appendix.

Comment: Try adding `\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage` after you've started first appendix. It's your choice to move away from consistency... :)

Comment: related: [Remove blank pages in twosided book class without openany](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153057/579).  the recommended `\renewcommand{\chapter}` can be inserted just after the start of the first appendix; it doesn't have to be only in the preamble.  on the other hand, that should have the same effect as @Werner's comment to redefine `\cleardoublepage`.

Comment: Thanks, did not find that question. Would one normally have a blank page between different sections of the appendix?

Comment: @felbo -- whether or not a blank page is normally inserted between different appendices (*not usually* different *sections* of a single appendix), if the earlier appendix ends on a right-hand page, is usually a matter of a publisher's style.  if appendices are long, they should be treated just like other chapters.  yours, on the other hand, are rather short, so a case could be made for running them together (each starting on a new page, but not necessarily a right-hand page).

Comment: @barbarabeeton -- Thank you for the explaination. I always find it hard to understand how the layout of these reports should be done. What about the summary and the preface? Both of them are only a few lines, which leaves a blank page between. Should the preface also just start on a new page after the summary? How would that be done code-wise seeing as the chapters come after?

Comment: @felbo -- in the area with which i'm most familiar, the summary/abstract is not considered part of the work proper, so it would certainly go on a page by itself.  and the preface, although it is part of the front matter *is* considered part of the work, so it would start on a new right-hand page.  but i can't speak for all fields.  if you do decide you want that, though, you need to preserve the original value with `\let\originalcleardoublepage\cleardoublepage` and then when you want to restore it, invoke `\originalcleardoublepage`.